# Fullcalendar shows wrong day in month view

Tags: fullcalendar, jscript

I'm using Fullcalendar within a Asp.Net project and I'm using the function 'events' to refresh items in my calendar.

I'm putting events in myArray to pass it in the callback function as below:

```
var event = {
                title: 'Disponível',
                start: moment(horario.DtInicio),
                end: moment(horario.DtFim),
            }
myArray.push(event);
```

where `horario.DtInicio` and `horario.DtFim` is a Asp.Net json Date (eg. `"/Date(1423321200000)/"`)

When I show callendar in month view, this date shows in 02/06/2015 (mm/dd/yyyy), but when I toggle to other view, this event shows in 02/07/2015. The real date is 02/07/2015.

Has anyone faced this situation?

Comment: Hi, I also am experiencing this issue with FullCalendar 2.2.6. I tried @RodrigoDela's suggestion of setting the `timezone` to 'local' but this did not help.

Comment: @jkndrkn maybe you could post a fiddle, so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @RodrigoDela, my issue was related to an out-of-date version of moment.js

Comment: Does anybody got any answer to resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

Try to set the timezone for the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullcalendar({
    timezone : 'local',
    ...
});
```

Comment: I am also experiencing the issue that the OP is facing. Setting the timezone to "local" did not help. I am running FullCalendar 2.2.6, jQuery 2.1.3, jQuery UI 1.10.4 and moment.js 2.8.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, still wrong yet.

The constructor of calendar is like that:

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            theme: true,
            lang: 'pt-br',
            //timezone: 'America/Sao_Paulo',
            timezone: 'local',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            allDaySlot: false,
            events: $scope.eventsCallBack
        });

Comment: It works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/ed05a85w/1/ I am using your config @GabrielAyussoGuimarães Please make sure you are using the latest fullcalendar release.

Comment: I am using FullCalendar v2.4.0 and in which file i need to add this property,not sure in fullcalendar.min.js or moment.js ?

Comment: This is the init of your calendar, so you need to add it in your code.

Comment: AWESOME! THANKS!!

Comment: If you have problems with filters and have no idea why your event rendering not in day you want that is answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

As RodrigoDela suggested, try setting your `timezone`. If that does not help, then try what worked for me.

Setting the `timezone` alone to "local" did not fix the issue for me. Updating moment.js from 2.8.3 to 2.8.4 did fix the issue.

For reference, I am running the following versions of FullCalendar and its dependencies:

- FullCalendar 2.2.6
- jQuery 2.1.3
- jQuery UI 1.10.4
- moment.js 2.8.4

Additional details regarding my debugging process and fix [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/225).